# Question About Nested Interval Property

Tags: real-analysis, notation

This is a theorem from Abott's Real Analysis textbook.

Theorem 1.4.1 (Nested Interval Property)

For each $n\in N,$ assume we are given a closed interval $I_n = [a_n,b_n] = \{x\in R : a_n\leq x\leq b_n \}$. Assume also that each $I_n$ contains $I_n{_+}{_1}$. Then the resulting sequence of closed intervals

$I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq I_3\subseteq I_4\subseteq \cdots$

has a nonempty intersection; that is, $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} I_{n} \neq \emptyset$

QUESTION HERE:

Wikipedia says that an given an interval $I_n$ and $I_n{_+}{_1}$, $I_n{_+}{_1}$ is a subset of $I_n$ which makes total sense. But in the theorem it reads that the "resulting sequence of closed intervals" and below it says $I_1$ is a subset of $I_2$, so on and so forth, which is not true. Am I misreading this?

Comment: If you have quoted the theorem exactly, you are right and Abbot's book has a typo in that all the containment symbols should be reversed to agree with what is said verbally (and with other statements I've seen of nested interval theorem).

Comment: @coffeemath The OP's quote was actually not exact: see screenshot below.

Answer (score 1):

The book says
$$I_1 ⊇ I_2 ⊇ I_3 ⊇ I_4 ⊇···$$
(you have it flipped)

[image]

Comment: Although this remark is very useful, you'd better write it as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/2076880)

Comment: @Dominique After having voted like you, I now think this answers exactly the OP's question, so it was better to edit it as an answer than as a comment. I shall improve it with a screenshot of the book.